# Error Executing tool: ArcPY

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, 3d-analyst

I am stuck with a code due to a RunTimeError: Object: Error in Executing tool
and I really can't find the mistake.
The code is

```
# Now, the script for "Adding Surface Info" to the network, using the raster with MAX MEAN defined just above
# Set the raster of input, on the basis of the MAX MEAN
inSurface = "C:/B3061239/!!! WORK !!!/RAS_for_maxmean/", NameRasList[MEANlist.index(max(MEANlist))]
# NOTE that NameRasList[MEANlist.index(max(MEANlist)) has been calculate before
method = "BILINEAR"
if inSurface:
    print "Got inSurface"
# Create list of feature classes
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print str(len(fcList))
# Process: Add Surface Information
if fcList:
    print "Got featureclasses"
    for fc in fcList:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
        print desc.name
        # Determine if the feature is 2D
        #if not desc.hasZ:
            #if desc.shapeType == "Polygon":
                # Desired properties separated by semi-colons
                #Prop = "Z_MIN;Z_MAX" 
            #elif desc.shapeType == "Point":
                #Prop = "Z"
            #elif desc.shapeType == "Multipoint":
                #Prop = "Z_MIN;Z_MAX;Z_MEAN"
            #elif desc.shapeType == "Polyline":
                #Prop = "LENGTH_3D"
            # Execute AddSurfaceInformation
    arcpy.ddd.AddSurfaceInformation(fc, inSurface, "Z_MAX", method, "", "1", "0", "NO_FILTER")
print "Completed adding surface information."
```

Comment: Can you please edit you post to use code formatting? It's very hard to read currently as a wall of text.

Comment: Is this a real path to some data : inSurface = "C:/B3061239/!!! WORK !!!/RAS_for_maxmean/"? I would certainly get rid of the spaces and "!!!" stuff. If you want a real answer for this, start by telling us ArcGIS version etc and perhaps provide the code and actual error message you are getting.

Comment: Try changing inSurface = "C:/B3061239/!!! WORK !!!/RAS_for_maxmean/" to "inSurface = r"C:/B3061239/!!! WORK !!!/RAS_for_maxmean/"    The change is the raw string "r"   its hard to see the change.

Comment: @TristanForward raw string is not required as the string variable does not contain any backslashes.

Comment: Can you edit your post to add the entire error traceback, not just the final error message.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an error handler to locate the source of the error....

```
try:
    import sys, traceback
    #YourCodeHere

except arcpy.ExecuteError: 
    print "error"
    msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2) 
    arcpy.AddError(msgs)  
    print msgs
except:
    print "error"
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
    pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n" + str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    print pymsg + "\n"
```